# Attmepting to close a popup using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS rookie, so be patient with me. I just created a js popup using this code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp and now I am attempting to add a simple close button to the top right corner to direct users to. I looked at some of the other close button threads and none of them seemed like they would integrate into my js code.

Comment: Show us what you have tried:)

Comment: `<button onclick=close()>X</button>` ; seems easy to integrate...

Comment: Thanks Dan. Where would I go about putting that code?

Comment: You can add code to your post by following the advice on the [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 0):

i Well searched "js close button" on the site which brought up several threads but none of them seemed to have an easy addition to the js script (Im assuming thats where the code should go). Again. Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class and simply display and hide it on button click

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: lightBlue; 
    background-color: grey;
}

   
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

.close {
    color: black;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much!